# Kotlinx-serialization does not recognize Json.parse() or Data.serializer()

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I tried [following example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to parse a Json String to corresponding object.

1. The `Data` is marked with `@Serializable`

Both functions `Json.parse()` and `Data.serializer()` are makred red and thus not recognized.

I tried that with kotlinx-serializable 0.9.1 and 0.10.0, **in vain**

**What did I forget?**

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353680/getting-kotlinx-serialization-working-in-multiplatform-project